# Where can I find a good NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC Reference Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, reference-application

Where can I find a good NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC Reference Application? I downloaded S#arp and this seemed to be a lot more than I needed (IOC and CodeGen via T4). I might work my way up to this later, but I need something smaller at first.

Any simple examples? I just want to pick up how NHibernate Session handling works in ASP.NET MVC.  And maybe how some simple query scenarios work. Still trying to grasp how a [SELECT DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558974/nhibernate-select-distinct-equivalent-for-a-page-filter-northwind) would be done in NHibernate and through to the View via the ViewData.

Comment: Is it just me? but I get errors when trying to download the source for Code Camp Server.

Comment: no I got the source alright.... You need to have an SVN client installed. You can find one here http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads for windows.

Comment: It is by far the BEST svn client for windows - there is also a Visual Studio add in that will integrate with TortoiseSVN called http://www.visualsvn.com/

Comment: I was using TortoiseSVN and wasn't able to download. Maybe its my companies annoying firewall/proxy. I think the new one they just put in looks for WebDAV-ish traffic over port 80.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would try to tackle them independently.

Before Billy McCafferty wrote sharp-architecture he wrote, what I think is, a must read on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx) about best practices with NHibernate. Also, I have just discovered  some [DimeCasts](http://dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/MVC)(by Kyle Baley) under the MVC tag that are very good.

[Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) created the ASP.NET [MVC Storefront](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/) video series which he goes over a lot of patterns and practices. The backend written is using Linq to SQL but can be adapted with [LinQ to NHibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/16/Linq-for-NHibernate.aspx). More recently he has also done a video series on [TekPub](http://tekpub.com/preview/nhibernate)  - NHibernate with [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/blog/). Lastly (for NHibernate) there is the [Summer of NHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/)

The [S# arch source](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) itself now comes with a sample projects as well.

Finally, there is [**Code Camp Server**](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/) that is built with MVC.Net and NHibernate and uses pretty much every open source tool you can think of...

*sidenote*

If your interested in getting rid of those annoying XML files when using NHibernate you might also want to look at [fluent](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/02/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-1.aspx).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the code project link. This helps even though this isn't MVC, it is WebForms with NHibernate, and uses and interesting method of managing the NHibernate Session.

Comment: ya it is quite interesting. I also got a lot out of the MVC Storefront series. Esp the episode showing the uses of structure map...

Comment: I agree. I will get a lot out of looking at the Storefront code and videos.

Answer (score 3):

[Code Camp Server](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/)

Comment: Not the easiest project to digest for those new to either MVC or NHibernate. It also relies heavily on command processing, which adds to the learning curve. Is there a guide to walking through the source?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a full sample application or anything but it's a pretty well designed ASP.NET MVC project framework written around DDD/nHibernate etc.

http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/

Comment: Actually #arc comes with two reference applications.

Comment: Sharp Architecture, what I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

you can check these websties

http://nhibernateasp.codeplex.com

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one:

http://dataguidance.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

BuddyJoe, you can I find a good NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC Reference Application
NHibernate Mvc Code [nhibernatetutorial.com](http://nhibernatetutorial.com)