# nhibernate collection set mapping to avoid n+1 select and duplicate rows with fetch join

Tags: nhibernate, join, mapping, set, fetch

I have a object table and object aliases table.

The aliases is just a set collection of strings:

```
object.Aliases
```

If I map the collection like this:

```
<class name="Object" table="Object" lazy="false">
    ...
    properties...
    ...
    <set name="Aliases" table="Aliases" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="join" >
      <key column="ObjectId" />
      <element column="Name" type="String"/>
    </set>
    ...
</class>
```

then

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof (T)).List<T>();
```

from base repository which fetches all objects, returns duplicates for each alias. Why? how can I get rid of the duplicate objects in the list?

Thank you all for your time.

EDIT:
Updated mappings... but that's all the mappings. Aliases doesn't have it's own class as it's just a set of strings that needs to be loaded into `ISet<string> Object.Aliases`

Comment: are you asking about select n+1 or duplicates? or both?

Comment: Can you post a bit more info, the code and mappings for both tables

Comment: I'm asking for proper mappning to exclude n + 1 select and which will not return duplicates.
If I remove fetch="join" then result is without duplicates but has n + 1 select problem. If I leave fetch="join" then I have only one select but duplicate problem
As for mapping.. that's it, the only relevant part... but I'll update with more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by this, too, when I started using NHibernate.  That's how it works.  Because the mapping includes `fetch="join"`, it's using an SQL JOIN between the parent table and the child table, so the parent data is repeated for each child.  But then rather than filter out the extra instances of the parent, you get back a collection with one object per row in the query.  You need to indicate you want distinct objects.  Using ICriteria syntax, you can add `Transformers.DistinctRootEntity` to your query.

See [Get Distinct result set from NHibernate using Criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318157/get-distinct-result-set-from-nhibernate-using-criteria-api), and the link it mentions within.

Comment: Be careful with this method as it will give you a `cartesian` product. Depending on use case this might or might not be desirable.

Comment: thank you for the pointer. I finally managed to do it using client side `List<Object>().Distinct<Object>()`  `Transformers.DistinctRootEntity` also does it client side but I don't want to mess with writing Criteria object. My final solution was:
`return new List<Otpad>(base.GetAll().Distinct<Otpad>());`
Important: you need to have equals() defined in order for Discinct() to work as I recall, but my class already had it so this was convinient

Answer (score 0):

For the select n+1 problem add `batch-size="10"` to your mappings

```
<set name="Aliases" batch-size="10" ...
```

Comment: This is almost the solution, thanks for pointing it out! I say almost because it solves the n + 1 select. Unfortunately I have ~970 Objects for which I need to populate Aliases and I put batch-size="100" and resulting query is huge.. 0.5MB of text in the log (in ~10 queries total). This is huge compared to fetch="join" case so I think I'll rather see If I can apply DISTINCT to the join.